# Export Resultset to excel from linq to sql

Tags: sql, excel, linq-to-sql, csv

I need help to export data to Excel using linq. I got the data from linq but don't know how to export data. My code is as below

```
 using (DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext())
    {
        foreach (var mt in dc.Mapping.GetTables())
        {
            string sql = String.Format("Select * from {0} where ID = {1} ", mt.TableName, TenantID);
             var data = dc.ExecuteQuery(mt.RowType.Type, sql);
            //data is here now.
            string path = "D:\\CSvFiles\\";
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

            path = path + mt.TableName + ".csv";
            foreach (var item in data)
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, item.ToString());

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
using (DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext())
    {
        foreach (var mt in dc.Mapping.GetTables())
        {
            string sql = String.Format("Select columnName from {0} where ID = {1} ", mt.TableName, TenantID);
             var data = dc.ExecuteQuery(mt.RowType.Type, sql).ToArray();
            //data is here now.
            string path = "D:\\CSvFiles\\";
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

            path += mt.TableName + ".csv";
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, String.Join(",",data));
        }
    }
```

Comment: If the mapped row type is say `Customer`, won't `Join` use the `ToString` of tha `Customer` object -- something similar to `MyApp.Customer`? In which case the resulting string will look like `MyApp.Customer,MyApp.Customer,MyApp.Customer`.